# PHP - If a function parameter has a default value of null, should its type be declared as nullable?

Tags: php

Is it a best practice to mark as nullable (`?string`) the type of parameters that have a default value of `null`, given that the parameter is always passed as a string, for example (or some other non `null` value, it doesn't matter)? The default value of `null` is only specified to make the parameter optional.

```
function example(?string $param = null) {
    // Function logic here
}
```

The type declaration `string $param` is just fine since the parameter is always passed as a string, but since it has a default value of `null`, the type declaration perhaps doesn't accurately indicate the types that the parameter can have inside the function. So would the declaration `?string $param` (or `null|string $param`) be more appropriate?

Comment: `function example(?string $param){....}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: make a parameter type hint nullable if `null` is a meaningful value. (i.e. if it should be used in cases other than omission)

---

It's practically (and technically?) identical, i.e. function will accept an explicit `null`, even if the parameter is "not nullable" but has `null` as its default value.

However, the `null` default value makes it, as you already mentioned, an optional parameter (in that it can be omitted).

I have constructed this very bad design example to make a point:

```php
abstract class SomeCommand {
  function setParameter(string $parameter = '');
  function run(); 
  function runWithParameter(string $parameter = null); // version 1
  function runWithParameter(?string $parameter = null); // version 2
}
```

Assume that you can set a default parameter for the command, which is always a string. Let's look at the versions of `runWithParameter`:

- Version 1, IMHO, says, you can provide an override value for the parameter, but you can omit the parameter to keep the default.
- Version 2, IMHO, says, you can provide an override *and explicitly providing null **might** make a difference!* but you can omit it.

Please note, that in version 1 and 2 BOTH, you can distinguish between the parameter being omitted or `null` being provided. Via `func_get_args()` this will produce `[NULL]` and `[]` respectively (`$parameter` is `null` in both cases, though). *IMHO, it is a very BAD idea to rely on this difference/distinction!*

However, I think there is a semantic difference:
If you want the function to accept a **meaningful** `null` (besides "omission"), make the type hint nullable (`?string`), and if you want the function to only accept string, but it may be omitted, use `= null`.

This way, you can hopefully communicate, that a parameter given as `null` is meaningful or just used for omission, especially, if the function has more parameters.

(Corollary: if you want the parameter to always be provided, remove the default value, obviously, this can make sense to force the caller to make a conscious choice. Please beware, that an omitted or nullable parameter *might* be an indicator for two functions being forced into one, which, depending on the function complexity might be a code smell)

**update**

Since @shingo commented, that version 1 is not recommended: This concerns using `= null` to make a parameter *nullable*, i.e. like `setParent($parent)` in a tree. Here `setParent(Node $parent = null)` would work but would also be **bad**. Better: `setParent(?Node $parent)`, this makes the parameter non-optional and also clearly communicates the type the parent can have.

Comment: Version 1 is not recommended, it might make trouble. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.nullable

Comment: @shingo it indeed might make trouble. I also really dislike optional parameters in general (see Corollary) and I would be very careful to ever use version 1.

Comment: However, I believe the point the php manual is making for not recommending it, is the same I'm trying to make. It's in the context of making a parameter *nullable* (adding it to the type is strictly better), not in the context of making a parameter *optional*. Making a parameter non-optional in an extending class+function isn't proper anyway and will throw a compatibility exception. making an optional parameter nullable in an extending class+function actually works without problems